# android sqlite3:how to get julianday function's value from cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to compare to two time str,for example: 2014-06-24 and 2013-06-25.They're all formatted with "yyyy-MM-dd". In sqlite3,I can get my purpose by using this: "select julianday('2014-06-25') - julianday('2013-06-25')",which returns 365.

But when I use it in android,I can't get the value from cursor.Here is my code:

```
Cursor timeCursor = mDbHelper.rawQuery("select julianday('2014-06-25') -julianday('2013-     06-25')",null);
if (timeCursor.getCount() > 0 && timeCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int time = timeCursor.getInt(timeCursor.getColumnIndex("julianday('2014-06-25') -   
    julianday('2013-06-25')"));
}
```

But the time is 0.
so here's my question:How can I get the right value from the cursor or there is a better way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to spell the column name exactly, which is rather difficult.
Better use a column alias:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT ... AS d");
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("d"));
```

However, you *know* that there is only one column, so you can just use its index:

```
cursor.getInt(0);
```